# Why Does The Text Fade but Not The Image?

Tags: html, css

Heres a visual: http://cl.ly/image/2L3g1d0W1r1Y

The text fades fine, but the image on the left is instant and doesn't fade ad the same time as the text.  How do I get them to fade in at the same time for all browsers? It seems to work fine in chrome, but not in Firefox or Safari.

I'm a little confused by whats going on, but heres my html:

```
<ul class="action">
    <li><a class="visit-site" href="http://google.com">Visit Site</a></li>
    <li><a class="back-to-top" href="#portfolio">Back to top</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the css:

```
ul.action a.visit-site {
background: transparent url('../images/arrow-small-right-rest.png') no-repeat 0 2px;
padding-left: 18px;
color: #57585a;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s all ease;
-moz-transition: 0.5s all ease;
transition: 0.5s all ease;
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s all ease;
}

ul.action a.visit-site:hover { 
background: transparent url('../images/arrow-small-right-over.png') no-repeat 0 2px;
color: #3ee1df; 
}
```

With Sprite:

```
    ul.action a.back-to-top{
background: transparent url('../images/sprite.png') no-repeat 0 2px;
padding-left: 18px;
width: 13px;
height: 13px;
color: #57585a;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul.action a.back-to-top:hover{ 
background-position: 0 -63px;
color: #3ee1df; 
}
```

Comment: i don't think you can add transition to background images. I recommend you use `opacity()` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using something like jQuery with your overall design and development you can "animate" the "opacity" of the whole UL element you have, which should create the transition you want.

But opacity isn't supported in all browsers more so the older ones. There are cross browser solutions to it, but in all you want to adjust the opacity to create the transparency effect

Comment: I'm changing the color of the image and the link instead of just changing the opacity.. what would be the best solution for that?

Comment: I did not notice that, sorry. There is no changing an image if your asking what I think you are. An image is like solid mass, it is what it is. You can create the illusion of changing the the image background though In a couple means. You could either create a sprite which you would use in a rollover like manorism, or you make an image with a transparent background and the background color of the elment its in is the color of the image. Or you could create layers of images within elements to achieve the end goal. If all you want is the background though Id suggest the transparent image

Comment: where the background of the element is whatever color you want, then change that on the fly

Comment: I created a sprite and added the updated code to the main post, but instead of fading the new arrow in its scrolling to it.. Is there a way to get it to fade in on hover?

Comment: fade one out, reposition, fade one in?

Comment: got it to work with the first example here: http://css-tricks.com/fade-image-within-sprite/  thanks for the help!